# Set the maximum resolution for the camera

Tags: android, camera, resolution

I get a list of extensions and try to compare the first and last values:

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
int wc1=0, wc2 = 0, hc1 = 0, hc2 = 0, wf = 0, hf=0;
Camera.Size result = null;
for (int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++){
    result = (Size) sizes.get(i);
    if (i==0){
         wc1=result.width; hc1=result.height;
    } 
    if (i==sizes.size()){
         wc2=result.width; hc2=result.height;
    } 
    if (wc1 > wc2) {wf=wc1; hf=hc1;} 
    if (wc2 > wc1) {wf=wc2; hf=hc2;}         
}
params.setPictureSize(wf, hf);
```

Not determined the expression:

```
i==sizes.size()
```

How to set the last item in the list?
Thank you advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
List sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
```

// last item present in list is size of list minus 1

```
sizes.get(sizes.size()-1);
```

and your expression

```
if (i==(sizes.size()-1)){
         wc2=result.width; hc2=result.height;
    }
```